# App that analyses COM1 activity

Tags: serial-port

There's a old piece of software we run in our company that manages RFID cards tapping in/out to open doors.

We want to create an app who identifies who just touched in on a specific place (we have the id for that) and grab their 1st name, to say "Hi [NAME]" on a screen.

As I mentioned, the software is quite old and there are no APIs. It communicates with the RFID hardware via a serial port (COM1).

I was wondering if the best way to get the data I need is to somehow intercept the COM1 traffic and extract/look for the data I want.

Does this sound like the best way to go about it? Would it work, or would it be impossible to get names and numbers from the data being transferred?

Cheers,
Andre

Comment: There's no way to find out until you try.  We can't help you try.

Comment: Seems like you're omitting some details.  Is this access control system still in use?  Where is or on what hardware is this "old software" executing?  Is the serial port of the reader unused (a standalone unit) or connected to a controller box?  Since you don't know the API, why do you assume that writing to the serial port will only cause that data to be displayed on a screen? Are you aware that you can sniff an EIA/RS-232 line, but you cannot inject two Tx signals into one receiver?

Comment: Right, for more details: we still use the access control system. Software is running on a WinXP machine. There's a separate bit of hardware that controls all of the RFID communications throughout the building, then feeds that into the software via COM1.
I've tried running a serial port monitor, but as expected, all I get is loads of hexadecimal data.
Is there anyway I can decode that to see if it's encrypted or can be used for my app?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do access control, but one common topology is to have the UI and master database running on a PC (what you keep on calling *"software"* ?), a *controller* (the *"separate bit of hardware"* ?) that maintains a runtime database and grants access or denial, and remote readers.  The comm link between the PC and *controller* is for transferring database records and directives to the controller, and transaction logs back to the PC.  This would employ a binary protocol, typically unencrypted.  If you cannot obtain or figure out the binary protocol, then you are SOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you configure the software to use a port other than COM1, or configure the hardware so it's physical serial port is assigned to a different COM port?

If so, take a look at [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/).  It's a Windows driver that creates two COM ports on your PC with a virtual NULL modem between them.  Data going in on one side comes out on the other.

Here's how you'll set things up:

- RFID Reader connected to physical COM port (COMx)
- your program bridging COMx to COMy and sniffing the traffic
- com0com linking COMy (for your program) to virtual COM1 (for the legacy software)
- legacy software

You'll need to write a program to pass data between COMx and COMy while monitoring it for the information you're looking for.  Make it simple yet robust, since if it goes down you're reader will stop working.

## A Simpler Solution

If you only need to monitor one side of the communications, create a cable that connects the GND and RX pin of COM1 to another COM port.  Now your program can monitor that side of the conversation, without interfering with the legacy software.

Comment: Alright, this sounds promising. I can change the port it uses, though I'm a bit scared of breaking the whole thing. I actually just need to get the data coming in, not the one going out.
If I did connect the GND to another port, would I get different data than what I get by running a serial port monitor? In this case, I'm getting quite a bit of hexadecimal crap :)

Comment: You'll get the same data as a serial port monitor.  You're essentially creating a simple monitor by connecting the Receive and Ground pins to a second port.  If you need help decoding the hexadecimal crap, consider posting another question with some sample captures made from different cards.  Someone on SO might recognize the format and be able to help you with decoding it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, generally, you can look at RS232 signals, if that's the way you want to do it.  It's tricky because you need to "sniff" the signals, which means buying or making a rig that allows  the original signals to go through, and then gives you a way to attach to them as well.  And, you need to send the transmit and the receive signals to TWO serial ports (on the RX lines).  Then you'll probably want to get some "sniffing" software that allows you to look at what you're getting in time sequence (ideally, with time-stamps).  Some cutesy protocols also will use modem lines, so you may need to monitor those as well.

Or, try searching for "free serial port monitor" or "serial sniffer".

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried running a serial port monitor, but as expected, all I get is loads of hexadecimal data. Is there anyway I can decode that to see if it's encrypted or can be used for my app? Ideally I'd like to stay away from tinkering with the hardware